# "Null correlation not allowed" when trying to use bean with @CorrelationStrategy annotation

Tags: spring-integration

I am new to Spring Integration and am trying to use Java DSL configuration to specify a flow that aggregates messages using an class GroupPublishAggregator that has @Aggregator, @ReleaseStrategy, and @CorrelationStrategy annotations.

I suspect that I'm making a newbie mistake in the configuration, because what I see when the aggregator receives a message is "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Null correlation not allowed.  Maybe the CorrelationStrategy is failing?"  If I debug the framework code, I see that the AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler is invoking the default org.springframework.integration.aggregator.HeaderAttributeCorrelationStrategy instead of my strategy.

The configuration code looks like:

```
@Bean 
public GroupPublishAggregator publishAggregator() {
    //  This class has methods with @Aggregator, @ReleaseStrategy,
    //  and @CorrelationStrategy annotations.
    return new GroupPublishAggregator();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow publish() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(this.inputChannel())
            .wireTap("monitor")
            .aggregate(new Consumer<AggregatorSpec>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(AggregatorSpec aggregatorSpec) {
                    aggregatorSpec.processor(publishAggregator(), null);
                }
            })
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug. Will be fixed soon: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues/93

Meanwhile the workaround for you is like to use `CorrelationStrategyFactoryBean` and `ReleaseStrategyFactoryBean` as `@Bean` and with particular `correlationStrategy(CorrelationStrategy correlationStrategy)` and `releaseStrategy(ReleaseStrategy releaseStrategy)`, respectively.

The problem that we don't call `afterPropertiesSet()` for those `FactoryBean`s.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation that it should work.  I worked around it by falling back to XML configuration and specifying the strategy ref and methods there.

Comment: I've now verified a version of your workaround and can now run without the XML configuration, thanks.
My `@Bean` method creates a `CorrelationStrategyFactoryBean`, invokes the `setTarget()` method with my strategy,  invokes the `afterPropertiesSet()` method to force the default strategy to be overwritten, and returns the result of the `getObject()` method.